# Is Laravel 5.1 App:singleton not working properly?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Given this code, placed in the default file routes.php in Laravel 5.1:

```
    \App::singleton('CatalogsService', function(){
            return new CatalogsService;
        });   

Route::group(['prefix' => 'catalogs'], function() {
    Route::get('statesmx', function (){       

        return var_dump(app('CatalogsService'));
    });

    Route::get('statesmx2', function() {
        return var_dump(app('CatalogsService'));
    });

    Route::get('statesmx3', function() {
        return var_dump(app('CatalogsService'));
    });

});
```

Why am I getting a different instance of CatalogsService when navigating to the 3 defined routes?

localhost/catalogs/statesmx dumps:

```
object(App\Services\Common\CatalogsService)[152]
```

`localhost/catalogs/statesmx2` dumps:

```
object(App\Services\Common\CatalogsService)[153]
```

`localhost/catalogs/statesmx3` dumps:

```
object(App\Services\Common\CatalogsService)[154]
```

I was expecting to get the same Object Reference Id.

The only way to get the same reference is by adding the next code before the `Route::group....`

```
app('CatalogsService');
```

when I do it the 3 routes dump the same object reference:

```
object(App\Services\Common\CatalogsService)[106]
```

I don't get it why is this happening. For me it looks Laravel Singleton is not working properly unless there's something I'm missing about the way a Singleton in Laravel works.

Thank you in advance for any help or hint on this matter.

PD: I'm new to Laravel.

Answer (score 1):

> In software engineering, the singleton pattern is a design pattern that restricts the **instantiation** of a class to one object...

Therefore, each time you navigate between routes (each Request), the app creates a new instance that will be used across all the application. Even if you get the same object reference between requests it's not the same instance.

Singleton means: Create Single Object Instance for Each Request.

From the Laravel Doc:

> The singleton method binds a class or interface into the container that should only be resolved one time, and then that same instance will be returned on subsequent calls into the container.

The best place to bind a singleton is inside the `register` method of the `AppServiceProvider`.

```
$this->app->singleton('CatalogsService', function ($app) {
     return new CatalogsService;
});
```

Good Luck.

Comment: Hi. I think your are confused. Instance of a class and object are the same thing in the context of languages that support classes (JS is an particular case but is not the subject of this question). 
So if an instance is created, it means an object has been created. Such object has a memory address and a reference to this object points to its address.

Comment: In the singleton pattern the purpose is to make sure only one instance of a class exists so when something requests and instance/object of the class the instance returned must be the same and by the same it means the object/instance memory address must be the same. If the address is different then we are not talking about the same instance so in that case we don't have a Singleton.
That's why I'm wondering if the Singleton in Laravel is really a Singleton. It may be a Singleton but with a request lifespan. That's something I'm not sure about.

Comment: By Request, I mean "Http Request" not memory access !